# Hyperlink from document (Excel, Word, PDF) to a specified placemark inside the KML file

Tags: google-earth

I have been searching on the web and I couldn't find a solution.

I would like to hyperlink from a cell in an Excel spreadsheet to a placemark in my .kml file.

If insert a link and attach a file straight like `.../philipines.kml` then I have all placemarks in Google Earth. I need one only. I know that I can extract every placemark to a separate .kml, but is there some quicker solution?

I tried to grip the placemark via id and then input into my Excel hyperlink like this:
`.../philipines.kml#ninoy-aquino`

Unfortunately the file opens the same like without this extension.